# StrongLoop REST API "hasManyThrough" include filter always returns empty

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs, strongloop

**Premise**

Pretty short and simple. In my testing/learning environment for StrongLoop, I have set up two models: CoffeeShop and Person. Persons can have many "employers", and CoffeeShops can have many "employees". This relationship is maintained by a "hasMany"/"through" type relationship on both the CofeeShop and Person models.

**Problem**

When querying either model through the REST API, an include filter always returns an empty array for the associated relation, even if relations exist. In other words, the API call

`http://localhost:3000/api/CoffeeShops/67/employees`

works as expected, but

`GET: http://localhost:3000/api/CoffeeShops/67/?filter={"include":["employees"]}`

Does not.

Could anyone help me figure out why this is? I've attached pictures and the .json model definitions files as well.

```js
// /common/models/coffee-shop.json

{
  "name": "CoffeeShop",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {
    "name": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    },
    "city": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    },
    "numberEmployees": {
      "type": "number"
    },
    "ownerId": {
      "type": "number"
    },
    "isSmallBusiness": {
      "type": "boolean"
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {
    "owner": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "Person",
      "foreignKey": ""
    },
    "employees": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "Person",
      "foreignKey": "employerId",
      "through": "CoffeeShopPersonEmployeeEmployer"
    }
  },
  "acls": [],
  "methods": {}
}

// /omon/models/person.json
{
  "name": "Person",
  "plural": "Persons",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {
    "name": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    },
    "age": {
      "type": "number"
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {
    "shops": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "CoffeeShop",
      "foreignKey": "ownerId"
    },
    "employers": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "CoffeeShop",
      "foreignKey": "employeeId",
      "through": "CoffeeShopPersonEmployeeEmployer"
    }
  },
  "acls": [],
  "methods": {}
}

// /common/models/coffee-shop-person-employee-employer.json
{
  "name": "CoffeeShopPersonEmployeeEmployer",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {},
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {
    "person": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "Person",
      "foreignKey": "employeeId"
    },
    "coffeeShop": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "CoffeeShop",
      "foreignKey": "employerId"
    }
  },
  "acls": [],
  "methods": {}
}
```

[Images of REST requests](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYMkU.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

in your **CoffeeShopPersonEmployeeEmployer** Model:

add foreign keys properties:

```
"properties": {
    "CoffeeShopId": {
      "type": "number",
      "required": true
    },
    "PersonId": {
      "type": "number",
      "required": true
    }
}
```

and ajust the relations :

```
"relations": {
    "person": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "Person",
      "foreignKey": "PersonId"
    },
    "coffeeShop": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "CoffeeShop",
      "foreignKey": "CoffeeShopId"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have implemented your solutions, as well as updated the corresponding database tables, but the resulting behavior is still identical.